# Android: Add words to SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, colors, textview, spannablestring

I'm working on something and my ultimate goal is to

A. Have different colored words in a TextView

B. Take input from the user and put that word into the TextView with a specific color

http://puu.sh/9wpuU/fcc558a48a.png

So what I tried to do is in the OK button in my alert builder I took a SpannableStringBuilder, appended the new user input text, and set that span to a certain color. But it deletes all the previous color spans I had (I assume because you can only have one span at a time in a SpannableStringBuilder?) Any way to get around this? Here is what I tried. EDIT entire class is there now

```
public class WritingScreen extends Activity {
String title;
String text;
String userInput;
TextView story;
SpannableStringBuilder sb;
ForegroundColorSpan fcs;
int colorTracker;
int currentCharCount;
int nextCharCount;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.writing_screen);
    story = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storyText);
    sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(story.getText().toString());
    fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
    currentCharCount = story.getText().length();


}
public void addTextClick(View v){
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Input Word")
            .setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                            value = " " + value;
                            sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(story.getText());
                            sb.append(value);
                            nextCharCount = sb.length();
                            sb.setSpan(fcs, currentCharCount, nextCharCount, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            story.setText(sb);
                            currentCharCount = nextCharCount;




                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        }
                    })
            .show();

    }

}
```

That gives me this

http://puu.sh/9wq7z/7b7fb2f909.jpg

When I input OK jj meh in a row. I want them all to stay the color I assigned each word in the first place. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `story.getText().toString()` will convert the current Spannable into a String, which loses all markup information. You should use `sb.append(story.getText())` instead.

Secondly, you must **create a new `Span` each time** -- from the code of `setSpan()`, it looks like if the same span is found already in the builder, it will be changed. That's probably the reason you're losing your previous formatting.

For example:

```
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW };
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(colors[new Random().nextInt(colors.length)]);

SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(mTextView.getText());
int currentCharCount = sb.length();
sb.append(mEditText.getText().toString().trim());
int nextCharCount = sb.length();

sb.setSpan(fcs, currentCharCount, nextCharCount, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mTextView.setText(sb);
```

Comment: I tried what you said, I got rid of the text line and now have   

sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(story.getText());   
        sb.append(value);   
        nextCharCount = sb.length();
        sb.setSpan(fcs, currentCharCount, nextCharCount, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);   

Still the same result unfortunately.

Comment: @user3055557 Mmm, ok. Please expand/update your snippet to get more context.

Comment: OK I added the entire class, hope it helps!

Comment: Hey it works great! I was very close, the main difference I noticed was you create a new fcs every time, do you think that was it? Or was it just the way I was trying to update sb?

Comment: @user3055557 Yes, that's precisely it. Check the source code for `SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan()`. If you supply a previous span, it's updated.